# Accessing elements inside dom-repeat in attached

Tags: polymer

I would like to to have access to the elements inside of a `dom-repeat`. Here, `el` returns empty array:

```
<dom-module id="child-element">
    <template>
        <div id="ida">
            <ul>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{user}}" id="items">
                    <li class = "classa">{{item.name}}</li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        ChildElement = Polymer({
            is: 'child-element',
            factoryImpl(users) {
                this.user = users;
            },
            properties: {
                user: {
                    type: Array
                }
            },
            attached: function() {
                var el = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("#ida .classa");
                console.log("el",el);
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

How can I access the dynamically created elements inside the `dom-repeat` from elsewhere in Polymer?

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QbFtGHRt50BEmY25Byzm?p=preview) is a link to the the full version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When attached is called the children may not be initialized yet. Wrap your code in an async function.

```
attached:function(){
  this.async(function() {
   // access sibling or parent elements here
     var el = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#ida .classa");
     console.log("el",el);
  });
}
```

This is documented in the  [Developer guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-order)

Comment: Great! My head would crack if I banged it for one more day!

Comment: How do I call this.async from another function called from inside attached? Like attached: function(){ ymaps.ready(anotherFunction)};   
anotherFunction: function(){this.async ..... ????}

Comment: @Nazerke if 'anotherFunction' doesn't have a reference to 'this' (the polymer element) you can always refer to the base Polymer element `Polymer.Base` as in
```Polymer.Base.async(function() {
  /* do something */
});```

Comment: "How do I call this.async from another function...?"  -- You can use `.bind(this)`, as in `ymaps.ready(anotherFunction.bind(this))`

Answer (score 6):

So, although the question did not ask to access the elements by their `id`, that is still an acceptable way of accessing those elements, though not as answered by @Maksym Galich.

Instead of accessing via the `this.$` object, the proper way to access a *dynamically-created* element is through the `this.$$(selector)` method.

From the documentation on [Node Finding in the Local DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding):

> Polymer automatically builds a map of statically created instance nodes in its local DOM, to provide convenient access to frequently used nodes without the need to query for them manually. Any node specified in the element’s template with an id is stored on the this.$ hash by id.
>
> **Note: Nodes created dynamically using data binding (including those in  dom-repeat and dom-if templates) are not added to the this.$ hash**. The hash includes only statically created local DOM nodes (that is, the nodes defined in the element’s outermost template).
>
> ...
>
> **For locating dynamically-created nodes in your element’s local DOM, use the $$ method:**
>
> this.$$(selector)
>
> $$ returns the first node in the local DOM that matches selector.

(**Emphasis** in the above text was mine)

My own personal note:

**NOTE:** Notice that **this.$$** is *not* an object, but a method. Therefore, simply printing all elements with an `id` is *not* doable with `this.$$`, but locating a specific dynamically-created element *is*, which is actually what I need it for - and likely what you need it for too :)

Answer (score -2):

You can't get the list of elements in dom-repeat, but you can use id for each element in dom-repeat. Like this

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{dataView}}">
    <neon-animatable id="{{item.id}}">
        <inner-content data="{{item.content}}"></inner-content>
    </neon-animatable>
</template>
```

And get element via next select

```
var el = this.$['something_id'];
```

Comment: In my specific situation selector consists of both id and class. So how would I substitude class? I'm asking for all the li elements with a class and which are inside an element with id.There is a link to plunker in the end of the question

Comment: If I resort to your solution at last, how can I generate id?Because I don't have id in my data

Comment: Also, would be great if you could provide link where it says that I can't get the list of elements in dom-repeat

Comment: I am still unable to get access to the element with this.$ when specifying an `id`. After logging `this.$` to the console, only the elements that are defined outside of the dom-repeat are included, even though I can inspect the HTML and see that the id's for the elements exist...

Comment: This answer is *wrong* -- to access a **dynamically-created element**, you must use the `this.$$(selector)` method. From the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding).