# Polymer 1.0: Accessing elements by id in dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

This question has *almost* been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133767/accessing-elements-inside-dom-repeat-in-attached), with the main difference being that I want to access the elements specifically by their `id` through Polymer's `this.$` syntax. There *is* an answer on the linked question that says how to do this, but it doesn't work in my instance, and I don't think there's anything special I'm doing (which makes me think that answer is wrong). *Edit*: I've answered that question with my solution here as recommended, but I think the specificity of using an element `id` still warrants this question being separate.

So, onto the question. I have the following setup:

```
<div id="anElement">Content</div>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myItems}}">
  <div id="{{item.name}}>{{item.content}}</div>
</template>
<button on-click="listElements"></button>

...

properties: {
  myItems: {
    type: Array,
    value: function() {
      return [
        { name: "item1", content: "First item" },
        { name: "item2", content: "Second item" }
      ]
    }
  }
},

listElements: function(e) {
  console.log("this.$: ", this.$);
}
```

Output on button click:

```
this.$: 
  anElement: div#anElement.style-scope
```

I can inspect the HTML on the resulting page and see that there are two `<div>`'s that have the expected id's of `item1` and `item2`, yet they are not listed in the output from `listElements`.

In actuality, the elements in the `dom-repeat` are other custom elements with methods that I need to access and use in the click handler, but not being to access them directly is an issue.

I've inspected some of the [Polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html), and haven't found the reason why this is the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing elements inside dom-repeat in attached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133767/accessing-elements-inside-dom-repeat-in-attached)

Comment: That question has an accepted answer, and the method that was accepted is inherently different than accessing specifically by `id`. I could write my answer there, but accessing specifically by the `id` of the element was the purpose of this question/answer.

Comment: You are right I guess. There are probably dozens of similar questions anyway and it also needs 5 votes to get it made a duplicate.

Comment: I went ahead and answered in the other question though. And yes, I did see a few questions out there (other than SO) that had the same question but no answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, after a little more digging through the documentation, the answer was right there. Just thought I'd share since I have seen answers out there that are wrong!

From the documentation on [Node Finding in the Local DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding):

> Polymer automatically builds a map of statically created instance nodes in its local DOM, to provide convenient access to frequently used nodes without the need to query for them manually. Any node specified in the element’s template with an id is stored on the this.$ hash by id.
>
> **Note: Nodes created dynamically using data binding (including those in  dom-repeat and dom-if templates) are not added to the this.$ hash**. The hash includes only statically created local DOM nodes (that is, the nodes defined in the element’s outermost template).
>
> ...
>
> **For locating dynamically-created nodes in your element’s local DOM, use the $$ method:**
>
> this.$$(selector)
>
> $$ returns the first node in the local DOM that matches selector.

(**Emphasis** in the above text was mine)

My own personal note:

**NOTE:** Notice that **this.$$** is *not* an object, but a method. Therefore, simply printing all elements with an `id` is *not* doable with `this.$$`, but locating a specific dynamically-created element *is*, which is actually what I need it for - and likely what you need it for too :)

**NOTE 2:** Adding this after actually taking my own advice and using `this.$$(selector)`. Remember that it is a selector, so if you are looking for an element by its `id`, remember to preface with `#`, i.e. `this.$$('#myElement')`!

Comment: This is the most FAQ for Polymer :D

Comment: Interestingly, across a number of questions here on SO, I have yet to see this answer. The question I linked to in particular had an answer that said to simply use the `this.$['elementID']` for elements created by a `dom-repeat`, so I figured I'd share :)

Comment: No prob :) You can add you answer there as well. I marked this question as duplicate anyway.

Comment: One workaround that may be helpful for others: if you don't need to directly call a method but are just 'setting' data, you may just change the data that is bound to the child element, and have an observer in that element act accordingly.